# Trying to activate PHP function using button click with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to call a PHP script/file that will read data off of an HTML table. I want to press a button so that the PHP script/file will activate and read the data off of the HTML table into a database using MySQL.

My AJAX script is not activating the PHP file.

The HTML button code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-block" id="save">Save Workout</button>
```

The AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#save").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'addWorkoutTEST.php',
                success: function() {
                    alert("hello");
                }
            });
        });
});
```

The incomplete PHP code (does not contain DB code) - based off of https://brennanhm.ca/knowledgebase/2015/11/import-html-table-into-mysql-table/

```
<?php

require_once ('simple_html_dom.php');

$table = file_get_html('addWorkout.php');

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'workoutLogger');

foreach($table ->find('tr') as $tr) {    
    $exercise = $tr->find('td', 0)->plaintext;
    $weight = $tr->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
    $sets = $tr->find('td', 2)->plaintext;
    $reps = $tr->find('td', 3)->plaintext;

    $exercise_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $exercise);
    $weight_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $weight);
    $sets_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $sets);
    $reps_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $reps);
}
?>
```

I can't get a success message to pop up.

Comment: Have you determined that your click event is actually occurring? Just put an alert before your AJAX call to determine if it is or not.

Comment: Yes. The click event is working. I put the alert before the AJAX call and it appears whenever the button is clicked.

Comment: You’re actually submitting it the old fashioned way because of <button type=“submit”.  Replace it with type=“button” and then troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Are you going to be passing data from the web page at some stage and passing it via an AJAX Call? It seems that is where you are intending to get to eventually.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was keeping the  and wrapping the button around a form with the action "addWorkoutTEST.php", that did it perfectly.

```
                <form action="addWorkoutTEST.php">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-block" name="save">Save Workout</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: Well you should do that anyway but surely you still want to submit via your AJAX call to do the rest of what you want. i.e passing data,

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes, that's a good point. While my PHP code will scrape the HTML data from a saved file, the saved file does not contain the actual contents of the table. I need to be able to pass the contents of the table.

Comment: I've added an answer that will solve your form submit issue via  AJAX. Give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the default Form Submit action you just need to add in the `event.preventDefault();`

Something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(event){ // must include event here to match the object in the next line. It can be called anything.
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submit
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addWorkoutTEST.php',
            success: function() {
                alert("hello");
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert("ERROR: " + request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If javascript is disabled for whatever reason, you need to decide what action to take. With what you have so far in your answer to your form with the added action, that would be the fallback in such a case. It's something you need to think out and decide upon.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it from here and get back to you.